# Go - convert string which represent binary number into int

Tags: go

I wrote a stupid solution for this, any better recipe?
As you can see lots of useless conversions there.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "math"
)

func conv(str string) int {
    l := len(str)
    result := 0.0
    for i,n := range str {
        number,_ := strconv.Atof64(string(n))
        result += math.Exp2(float64(l-i-1))*number
    }
    return int(result)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(conv("1001"))
}
```

Comment: The answers below are recommended, but if you really want to do the conversion yourself, you can do it without any help from libraries. Make `result` an int, and for each iteration of the loop, `result = (result<<1)|(n-'0')`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You want the [`strconv.ParseInt`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv#ParseInt) function, which converts from an arbitrary base, into a given bit size.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    if i, err := strconv.ParseInt("1001", 2, 64); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/U4hzu7HWLpR)

Answer (score 8):

For example, on Go 1,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    i, err := strconv.ParseInt("1101", 2, 64)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

Output:

```
13
```

Comment: Wow, they sure changed the `strconv` package for Go 1.

Comment: How can this be real? If we convert binary to SIGNED int (using ParseInt, not ParseUint function), "1101" must return "-3". If the first bit is 1, it means than number is negative, isn't it? Did I missed something?

Comment: @igronus: "Did I missed something?" Yes, you did. Strings for negative numbers have a negative sign (`-`) as a prefix. For example, `-3` decimal, `-11` binary.

Comment: @peterSO Really? If I read data from some hardware register (marked as containing int), I get "1101", and it equals "-3". There is no signs in binary data, only zeros and ones.

Comment: @igronus: Really. "Negative numbers are usually written with a minus sign in front." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_number The Go `strconv` package parses the usual case. You have a special case: two's complement binary representation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement To parse two's complement binary representation, write a simple Go function. https://play.golang.org/p/x_JtICLB6Pv

Comment: @peterSO Okay, thank you. Binaries in golang are quite strange for me.

Answer (score 0):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var digits = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

func convertBase(num, fromBase, toBase int) string {
    if num == 0 {
        return "0"
    }

    var result []byte

    n := num
    if n < 0 {
        n = -n
        result = append(result, '-')
    }

    var stack []int
    for n > 0 {
        remainder := n % toBase
        stack = append(stack, remainder)
        n /= toBase
    }

    for len(stack) > 0 {
        result = append(result, digits[stack[len(stack)-1]])
        stack = stack[:len(stack)-1]
    }

    return string(result)
}

func main() {
    var num, fromBase, toBase int

    fmt.Print("Enter the number: ")
    fmt.Scanln(&num)

    fmt.Print("Enter the base of origin: ")
    fmt.Scanln(&fromBase)

    fmt.Print("Enter the base destination: ")
    fmt.Scanln(&toBase)

    // Convert from the original base to decimal first
    decimalNum := 0
    n := num
    p := 1
    for n > 0 {
        remainder := n % 10
        decimalNum += remainder * p
        n /= 10
        p *= fromBase
    }

    // Convert the decimal number to the desired base
    result := convertBase(decimalNum, 10, toBase)

    fmt.Printf("%v based on %v = %v based on %v.\n", num, fromBase, result, toBase)
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).